# A build file WindowsService2.vshost.exe in my debug directory is not being deleted

Tags: c#, visual-studio

A build file WindowsService2.vshost.exe in my debug directory is not being deleted
It also restarts when I am killing it from "Windows Taks Manager". any solution?

Comment: is your instance of VS open ? if so you need to close it, else VS will spawn that process.

Comment: It's not a build file, per se. It's a debugging helper for Visual Studio.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.  Now you can delete it.  There are a few scenarios where the hosting process is required, like building to an untrusted network share, they are very uncommon.  Or just don't fret about it, there is no good reason to.

Comment: Thanks guys, @HansPassant's comment has worked as my solution.